# select specific div with same css class

Tags: html, css

i have 6 divs with the same css class, and want to add css on each div individually, without changing the css class (because there is a lot of code that gonna break if i change the classes) and also cant add any other on top of the current one. How do i select each div individually to add different css to each one?

```
<div class="c-transparencia-graficos__part"> ... </div>
<div class="c-transparencia-graficos__part"> ... </div>
<div class="c-transparencia-graficos__part"> ... </div>
<div class="c-transparencia-graficos__part"> ... </div>
<div class="c-transparencia-graficos__part"> ... </div>
<div class="c-transparencia-graficos__part"> ... </div>
```

for example i want to add on the first div a position absolute with top 0, but not on the other ones, and again, i cant add any css class or change the current ones.

Also (maybe this helps) inside the div there is some code that changes over the other divs, so maybe i can select a class using the childrens?
The problem with .c-transparencia-graficos__part .sample1 is that im changing te .sample1 class not the .c-tra... that im interested

There is any way?

Comment: can you use javascript??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go...

Use `:nth-child()` CSS selector. Read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child).

See the snippet below.

```css
.c-transparencia-graficos__part:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: blue;
}

.c-transparencia-graficos__part:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: red;
}

.c-transparencia-graficos__part:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: purple;
}

.c-transparencia-graficos__part:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.c-transparencia-graficos__part:nth-child(5) {
  background-color: green;
}

.c-transparencia-graficos__part:nth-child(6) {
  background-color: brown;
}
```

```html
<div class="c-transparencia-graficos__part"> ... </div>
<div class="c-transparencia-graficos__part"> ... </div>
<div class="c-transparencia-graficos__part"> ... </div>
<div class="c-transparencia-graficos__part"> ... </div>
<div class="c-transparencia-graficos__part"> ... </div>
<div class="c-transparencia-graficos__part"> ... </div>
```